# Sharepoint Deployment

Tags: sharepoint

I am creating an .STP for a site. But here I have a DLL file in BIN , a XAP file in 12 Hive Folder and few more custom entries in teh Web.Config. How do I include there in the .STP File? When I say IncludeContent when I create a .STP file for the Site , then also the above said things are not getting included.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way I know of that you can modify an exported STP file.

It is possible you could try renaming the extension to ZIP or CAB, see if you can view the file, check for the presence of the a Manifest.xml file and attempt to modify that way. Have never tried though

Answer (score 0):

A Site Template will not export your web.config settings, 12 hive files or assemblies. All of these can be provisioned through a SharePoint solution file (WSP) though. I would suggest researching how to create and deploy those.